# Exibir link clicável que vem do banco de dados

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-5, link

Quero exibir o Link que possa ser clicável, está aparecendo como texto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou usando o código abaixo, mas mesmo assim vem como texto e não consigo clicar:

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(item.Facebook))
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu seu problema Fabio Souza ??? Tem alguma duvida maior ???, Quer outras dicas ???, fico no aguardo de qualquer comentário.

Answer (score 0):

***Coloque:***

```
<a href="@HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(item.Facebook)">Texto do Link</a>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @virgilio eu acabei fazendo o inverso, ao salvar concatenei `client.Facebook = "<a href=\""+facebook+"\"  target=\"_blank\">Facebook</a>";` mas vou tentar fazer da forma que você disse, a final acho que seria mais fácil carregar apenas o link do banco e na exibição concatenar o conteúdo.